# Generate linux command with arguments in Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, scala, process

I am looking for a library (Java/Scala) that given a command and a list of arguments produces a `String` that if pasted into the bash terminal will execute the given command with all its arguments (properly escaped).

I am aware of [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class. It works well if I want to execute a command as a subprocess. What I am looking instead is a library that can generate a String representation of a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't normally suggest that people try to write their own escapers, but in this case it's not terrible because a bash single quoted strings will properly enclose every single character except NUL bytes and nested single quotes:

```
  public static String bashEscape(String[] arguments) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String arg : arguments) {
      if (arg.indexOf(0) != -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Shell arguments can't represent NUL bytes");
      }
      sb.append("'").append(arg.replaceAll("'", "'\\\\''")).append("' ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

This correctly escapes:

- All types of quoting, including single quotes, double quotes, backticks, and backslashes
- All forms of shell metacharacters, like `*?![]()|<>&;$` and spaces
- All regular alphanumeric characters, obviously
- Linefeed, backspace, and other control characters

The only thing to be aware of is that you and your shell need to agree on the character encoding when you hand it the string.

Comment: A small improvement would be to use `String#replace` instead of `String#replaceAll`, as we do not need regex matching in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could print out the command that the ProcessBuilder is going to run and then not run it. "cmd" would be whatever command your app is generating based on the arguments.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
String command = processBuilder.command().toString();
```

Comment: I tried this with `cmd="ls"`, which made `command` contain `[ls]`. When I copy-paste this into my shell, I get `bash: [ls]: command not found`. If I enter `ls` directly, it lists files as normal. Do you get a different result?

Comment: Oh right, processBuilder.command() returns a List<String> so you would need to either String.join("", processBuilder.command()) which would give you the command, or iterate through the list while adding each element to a String and it would work. I assume you would only really ever have a single element in the list so String.join("", processBuilder.command()) would be easy and simple.

Comment: You'd usually have multiple elements, e.g. `new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-l", "My File.txt");` If you join on `""` you get `ls-lMy File.txt` resulting in `ls-lMy: command not found`. If you join on spaces, you get `ls -l My File.txt` resulting in `ls: cannot access 'My': No such file or directory`. The equivalent bash command in this case should be e.g. `ls -l "My File.txt"` to preserve the space in the last argument

Comment: Maybe it would be more beneficial for you to post your code so I can accurately answer with an example that fits your needs. I understand processbuilder takes multiple parameters. Are you indeed filling it with multiple parameters? Do you have an example of how you're doing it? If it's possible to join them with spaces then does that not resolve the problem? Your command will run successfully if you're joining using spaces and your above ProcessBuilder example is indeed what you are using in your code.

Comment: I'm not OP, but no, in my example joining on spaces doesn't work because this fails to account for spaces within a single argument. You can be sure that OP would be using multiple parameters because they ask about a "command and a list of arguments" and ProcessBuilder does not support arguments without multiple parameters (e.g. you can't use `new ProcessBuilder("ls -l 'My File.txt'")` because ProcessBuilder does not invoke a shell).